# python: print a netlink message in hex

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, netlink

```
import os
import socket
import struct

...

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_NETLINK, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.NETLINK_ROUTE)
s.bind((os.getpid(), RTMGRP_IPV4_IFADDR))

while True:
   data = s.recv(65535)
   msg_len, msg_type, flags, seq, pid = struct.unpack("=LHHLL", data[:16])

   ...

   # dump data in hex
```

I would like to print the first 64 bytes of the data, `print data` returns garbage, I think this is because data needs to be unpacked?

I also tried `' '.join(str(x) for x in s[:len(s)])` but it doesn't help either. What would be the right way to dump data read from `netlink` socket?

Comment: The easy way is to say `data[:64].encode('hex')`.  This works for Python 2 only.

Comment: @js-on `data` is already a `bytes` string so there is not need to encode it. Just do `data[:64].hex()`

Comment: @TimRoberts, thanks for help.